# Publishing to Azure Virtual Machine with Web Deploy

Tags: azure, iis, permissions, windows-server-2008, webdeploy

I am trying to set up Web Deploy on Windows Server 2008 R2, I have installed Web Deploy and Web Management Service.

I know that I'm connecting to the server because I see the following in the log.

```
2015-06-19 12:13:59 100.72.108.11 HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=IAmAFish 8172 - 86.1.148.102 - 404 7 0 93
```

However, I'm receiving the standard error about checking that Web Deploy is running.

I suspect permissions are the issue and I'm currently trying to find 'IIS Manager Permssions' in IIS manager, after selecting the site. It's not there. How do I add this feature to IIS manager so that I can manage permissions?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the version of Web Deploy installed by Web Platform Installer does not include the full suite of tools and should not be used for this.

Instead, download Web Deploy from:

http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy

Be sure to restart IIS Manager to see the new icons.